# Why can't I get these extensions to work?

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

I can't seem to get IList.Union<> or IList.Concat<> to do anything.

Here's the code.  Why does this fail?

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DirectoryInfo C = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\");   // 5 files here
        IList<FileInfo> f = C.GetFiles();
        int a = f.Count;
        DirectoryInfo D = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\newfolder"); // 2 files here
        IList<FileInfo> g = D.GetFiles();
        int b = g.Count;
        f.Union(g);
        int c = f.Count;  // f remains at 5.  Why are these not unioning?
        f.Concat(g);
        int d = f.Count;   // f remains at 5. Why are these not concating?
    }
```

"f" does not change in any of these cases. How do I get a Union or Concat to occur?

Comment: When the expected behavior is wrong for a void call, a good habit is to check if there is a returned type. In your case you would have understood that the list is not modified but a new instance is created and returned. You can also directly have a look at the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Union` and `Concat` returns a new  `IEnumerable<T>` you need to assign it back:

```
f = f.Union(g).ToList(); // since the type is IList<FileInfo>
```

Comment: Same for `Concat` also

Comment: E.g., most of these methods *return* the result, rather than modifying the instance itself.

Comment: Good Lord, how tired must I be.  By the way, that answer won't compile... Union does return an IEnumerable, and f is an IList. How do I cast to the interface to make this work?

Comment: @Noob that's why I have added ToList call